# Apache Spark shell crashes when trying to start executor on worker

Tags: shell, scala, apache-spark

**Background**

I have been battling with Apache Spark and have worked out most errors except one. I have a Master and one Slave. I can start the master via

`./sbin/start-master.sh`

and then I can connect to it from the slave by

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx10g" ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://10.17.16.43:7077`

I then see the success message

`14/08/25 08:47:04 INFO worker.Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://10.17.16.43:7077`

All of these errors are repeatable (I have been at this for a while). I can telnet into the master from the slave just fine as is mentioned in most other tutorials. SSH is configured to not need passwords between master and slave (RSA keys) as mentioned elsewhere.

I have spark/conf/spark-env.sh set to the following. There are more lines that are commented out

```
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dspark.local.dir=/mnt/spark,/mnt2/spark -Dspark.akka.logLifecycleEvents=true"
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=`ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p' | head -1`
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=$SPARK_LOCAL_IP
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8090
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
```

I pulled those from various tutorials in hope that they would fix something.

Here is my master `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.17.16.43     aidan-workstation
10.17.16.49     ubuntu
```

And slave

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.17.16.49 ubuntu
10.17.16.43 aidan-workstation
```

**The Error**

When I run `./bin/spark-shell`

I get the following in the master terminal ( just posted the tail end of it the full output is [here](http://pastebin.com/3gwygj1b) )

```
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140825085822-0002/8 on worker-20140825084704-ubuntu-49237 (ubuntu:49237) with 8 cores
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140825085822-0002/8 on hostPort ubuntu:49237 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140825085822-0002/8 is now RUNNING
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140825085822-0002/8 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 1)
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140825085822-0002/8 removed: Command exited with code 1
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140825085822-0002/9 on worker-20140825084704-ubuntu-49237 (ubuntu:49237) with 8 cores
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140825085822-0002/9 on hostPort ubuntu:49237 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140825085822-0002/9 is now RUNNING
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140825085822-0002/9 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 1)
14/08/25 08:58:25 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140825085822-0002/9 removed: Command exited with code 1
14/08/25 08:58:25 ERROR client.AppClient$ClientActor: Master removed our application: FAILED; stopping client
14/08/25 08:58:25 WARN cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection...
```

And at the same time the slave outputs (tail as well full output is [here](http://pastebin.com/FH9Kb7zx) as well)

```
14/08/25 09:04:18 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" "-cp" ":/home/hduser/spark/conf:/home/hduser/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "akka.tcp://spark@aidan-workstation:60456/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "7" "ubuntu" "8" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ubuntu:55553/user/Worker" "app-20140825090434-0003"
14/08/25 09:04:18 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20140825090434-0003/7 finished with state FAILED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
14/08/25 09:04:18 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20140825090434-0003/8 for Spark shell
14/08/25 09:04:18 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" "-cp" ":/home/hduser/spark/conf:/home/hduser/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "akka.tcp://spark@aidan-workstation:60456/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "8" "ubuntu" "8" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ubuntu:55553/user/Worker" "app-20140825090434-0003"
14/08/25 09:04:19 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20140825090434-0003/8 finished with state FAILED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
14/08/25 09:04:19 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20140825090434-0003/9 for Spark shell
14/08/25 09:04:19 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" "-cp" ":/home/hduser/spark/conf:/home/hduser/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "akka.tcp://spark@aidan-workstation:60456/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "9" "ubuntu" "8" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ubuntu:55553/user/Worker" "app-20140825090434-0003"
14/08/25 09:04:19 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20140825090434-0003/9 finished with state FAILED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
```

You may notice that the times are off. This is my fault. I had to re run the programs at different times to get a clean output. This is not due to the program.

**What I want**

How can I connect my master and slave such that I can run Scala programs on a distributed system?

Comment: It might not be related at all, but is there a reason why you're not using the slave scripts in sbin?

Comment: I didn't know about them. I will look into that and see if that fixes anything

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No, sorry. I just gave up.

Comment: I not sure if this is of any help but I believe spark 1.0 was built for jvm 7, you seem to be using java 8. Possibly could lead to conflicts. I think the most recent version of spark has been built with java 8, could be worth trying.

Comment: Dunno if you tryed, can u run ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://master-hostname:7077 and see what happens? (master-hostname is the hostname of your master)

Comment: Try using a qualified host name when starting your master and in your spark client connections (e.g. `aidan-workstation.acme.com`) rather than just the hostname aidan-workstation. Add it to your hosts file

Comment: just a quick check, do you have the 7077 ports (or whatever port you use to connect to slave) opened on both master & slave?

Comment: @ZakukaZ This was years ago. Sorry. I gave up and don't use Spark anymore, so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I note from your logs that akka is using a simple hostname `aidan-workstation` rather than a fully qualified domain name like `aidan-workstation.acme.com`

```
akka.tcp://spark@aidan-workstation:60456/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler
akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ubuntu:55553/user/Worker
```

[From this user post](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/A-Standalone-App-in-Scala-Standalone-mode-issues-td6493.html) it "may" be the issue you're having

> I had to set SPARK_MASTER_IP in conf/start-master.sh to hostname -f instead of hostname, since akka seems not to work properly with host
>   names / ip, it requires fully qualified domain names.

You can try editing your hosts file to include a faked domain name.